# Solution to use Pascal/Delphi code in a python enviroment

Tags: python, delphi, binary, pascal

I have a web site using Django and Python as a backend language.

We need to integrate part of a Pascal/Delphi code into our system, the thing is, that this pascal code has more than 4 k lines, and there are some math operations with bytes and binary generation (main idea of the Script) that could slow down the process for people that have not interacted before with this language.

My question would be, what would you do in this situation, So far we have received just an idea of translating the code to Python ( this would need to translate the Binary generations and most of the 4k lines of the code)... I would like to know if there is another workaround to approach this situation in your opinion.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily convert the Delphi code in a high-performance REST backend and call the endpoints from your web solution in Python. As options for the backend you can consider RAD Server, DataSnap, Delphi MVC Framework, Horse, and many others available out there.